# Change Data Capture and LWC on Mobile App?

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobile, lwc-dom, change-data-capture

I Have a LWC component setup to use CDC to refresh the apex of a varity of objects this intern affects the DOM (icons change / menu options change etc) this works fine on desktop however on the Salesforce Mobile app it seems to cache the display (i need to phisicly close the app and reopen for the record to change, just refreshing doesnt work) i have also verified that cache is disabled in my org.

Can anyone tell me is CDC supported on mobile? i didnt see any indication that it wasnt.

- If not how would i refresh dom content based on the record being changed by a integration / 3rd party?

Comment: Change Data Capture is a mechanism not running on any clients - desktops or mobile. But the [empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) is, and it is explicitly not supported on mobile phones - and this is probably what you use.

Comment: @FelixvanHove your right im using lightning/empApi to subscribe to the CDC event, do you know of a method to do the same thing that is supported via the mobile app?

Comment: "Settings"-"Advanced"-"Clear Cached Data" in the Android app didn't help in your case? You could try build your own polling. Not that I recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) -

> The lightning/empApi module is supported in desktop browsers with web
> worker or shared worker support. It is not supported in the Salesforce
> mobile app.

As an alternative, you can use [cometD](https://github.com/cometd/cometd-javascript) to subscribe/unsubscribe to your streaming events.